How upload an image on a website with Android and AJAX?
I have a little website and I want to make an upload page from server side. The following code uses ajax and works with Chrome on a classic laptop. The code below shows the picture and uploads it. When I try to upload images from Android phones it doesn't work, but prints something, something, something which detects the file is not empty.
html code
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ajax upload test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<br> 
<form id="form" action="ajaxupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
<div id="preview"><img src="filed.png" /></div><br>
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<div id="err"></div>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

The JS part
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         url: "ajaxupload.php",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
   beforeSend : function()
   {
    //$("#preview").fadeOut();
    $("#err").fadeOut();
   },
   success: function(data)
      {
    if(data=='invalid')
    {
     // invalid file format.
     $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
     // view uploaded file.
     $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
     $("#form")[0].reset(); 
    }
      },
     error: function(e) 
      {
    $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
      }          
    });
 }));
});

And the PHP part
<?php
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' , 'pdf' , 'doc' , 'ppt'); // valid extensions
$path = 'qrcode/'; // upload directory
if(empty($_FILES['image']['name'][0])){
    print('this thing is empty');
 }else{
    print('Something, something, something');
 }
$img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
// get uploaded file's extension
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// can upload same image using rand function
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;
// check's valid format
if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) 
{ 
$path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
{
echo "<img src='$path' />";
}
}
?>

When I try to upload an image from an Android phone the code prints something something... it detects there is a file but doesn't show and upload it like it does using a laptop. I use Debian with apache2 and php8.2
Why this is not working with Android phones?

the code print something something... That does not tell us anything about what happens. Moreover its your own message. Instead you should tell us what happens that you display a message

The php code print this because i make a check to be sure if the file is detected or not.In this case he is but doesn't upload on the server side.

Too vague. You did not tell how you checked and how you decided that there was no upload. Tell also what you expected to happen.

A messages like missing missing is not very informative for a user. A pretty bad error description.

After many search i found that the default android browser doesn't support php very well.So i suggest to the user to open his chrome browser like this
<p>Check out <a href="https://somewebsite/" target="_blank">this website</a>.</p>

After chrome browser is open no more problem to upload files.
